# After upgrade to OSX 10.8.2 "latex: command not found"

Tags: macos, latex, latex-suite

I've been using the vim-latex suite on my mac (10.7.?) for months with no problem.  Over the weekend, I upgraded the OS to 10.8.2, and now my tex files fail to compile.  The compile command

```
\ll
```

produces no errors within vim, but no pdf-file gets produced.  If I drop to the command line in a terminal, the following command

```
latex document.tex
```

produces

```
-bash: latex: command not found
```

Similarly, for pdflatex.  I'm not sure if this is a path error, or if latex for 10.8.2 needs to be reinstalled.  I'm not sure how to proceed in either case.

Comment: Not a programming questio, really. But check to see if your .profile got overwritten or the defaultpath changed.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and typing:

```
export PATH=/usr/texbin:$PATH
```

seems to work fine in a shell. Although it no longer works if I open a new shell, this is a faster solution to re-downloading and re-installing the huge MacTeX program.

Comment: You might want to put this into your .bashrc and/or .bash_profile. That way, the correct path will be set when you open a new shell.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me after upgrading to OS X El Capitan. I found the latex executables in `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin`. So, I just added this to my .bashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin"
```

No need to reinstall.

Comment: Faced the same problem today.. this got me fixed.. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, the standard way for third party installers to add a directory to the path is to put a file under `/etc/paths.d`. TeXLive does this as part of the installation, but the OS upgrade probably blew it away.

You should be able to just create a new file under that directory containing just one line, the path the directory containing the TeX executables.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help; I'll remember it for future upgrades.  Prior to reading your post, I opened a terminal and looked in the /usr/texbin directory, and saw latex, pdflatex, etc, but when I tried to execute them, I still received the "latex: command not found" error.  I thought this odd, so I down-loaded and reinstalled MacTex, and now everything seems to be working again.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Yeah, reinstalling TeX will recreate the files as well.

Answer (score -1):

When setting the path via @petew's answer, `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin` may not be the correct version. On my system `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin` was what was needed. Make sure to check your texlive binaries to see what file you downloaded.